# ESP8266-01 ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, arduino-ultra-sonic

## Platform

- Hardware:                 ESP-01
- Development Env:      [Arduino IDE|
- Operating System:     [Windows|

## Settings in IDE

- Module:           [Generic ESP8266 Module|
- Flash Mode:           [DOUT]
- Flash Size:               [512KB]
- lwip Variant:                  |v2 Lower Memory|
- Reset Method:     [ck]
- Flash Frequency:          [40Mhz]
- CPU Frequency:        [80Mhz]
- Upload Using:     [SERIAL]
- Upload Speed:              [115200]

## Problem Description

i work in smart parking project witharduino uno using 8 ultrasonic sensors and esp8266-01, i connect TX ESP-01 to arduino uno TX and RX to RX and every sensor to one arduino pin, when upload code i connect GPIO0 to GND and after uploading remove it, when open serial monitor it open loop of reconnecting(restart) and display only 5 sensor with value 0 ,

Result:

```
connecting..... connected:
192.168.1.11   
Distance0 : 0   
setting /number failed:   
Distance1 : 0   
setting /number failed:   
Distance2 : 0   
setting /number failed:   
Distance3 : 0   
setting /number failed:   
Distance4 :    
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7) 
wdt reset   
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16    
tail 8   
chksum 0x2d 
csum 0x2d   
v8b899c12   
~ld
```

## My Code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "ْْْXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
#define WIFI_SSID "AYMAN" 
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "01357911" 
//#include <Servo.h>

//Servo myservo;
const int ULTRASONIC_PIN[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

void setup(){ 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD); 
  Serial.print("connecting"); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("."); 
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println(); 
  Serial.print("connected: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
}

void loop(){
  for(int x=0;x<8;x++){
     Serial.print("Distance");
     Serial.print(x);
     Serial.print(" : ");
     int result = readUltrasonic(ULTRASONIC_PIN[x]);
     Serial.print(result);
     Serial.println();
     if(result<150){
       Firebase_Setup(x);
      }
      delay(1000);
  }
  
  Serial.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  delay(1000);
}

int readUltrasonic(int pin){
 //Returns distance in cm
 pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(pin, LOW);

 pinMode(pin, INPUT);
 return pulseIn(pin, HIGH, (unsigned long)60000) / 29 / 2;
}
//>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Firebase_Setup(int number){
  Firebase.set("Slot 1", 1);
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
      Serial.println("setting /number failed:");
      Serial.println(Firebase.error());  
      return;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Please choose a better title.

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/a02-my-esp-crashes.html?highlight=watchdog#watchdog

Answer (score 0):

"wdt reset" most likely means Watchdog Timer reset the processor (ending your program).

Either turn the watchdog off or periodically call the function to extend its timeout.

Comment: i can't understand you and i don't know what watchdog is.
please explain with some code.